# Positon of DropDown list of ComboBox in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a ComboBox in my universal application, I want DropDown list open below of my combo not over it.
how can I change position of DropDown list of ComboBox in `UWP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DropDown of a `ComboBox` is actually a `Popup`, and the position where to show this `Popup` is defined in the code behind, and we can't access to it. One workaround is finding this `Popup` and relocate it when it is opened, but using this method we need to calculate the `VerticalOffset` property each time when it is opened, and there are quite many scenarios for different value of `VerticalOffset`.

So my suggestion is design a custom control which behavior like a `ComboBox`, for example I created a `UserControl` like this:

```
<Button x:Name="rootButton" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Click="Button_Click" MinWidth="80" Background="Transparent" Padding="0">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Width="{Binding ElementName=rootButton, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind selectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <FontIcon Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom" x:Name="menuFlyout">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 4" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 5" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Button>
```

and the code behind in this `UserControl`:

```cs
public sealed partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        selectedItem = "";
    }

    private string _selectedItem;

    public string selectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selectedItem"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        selectedItem = item.Text;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as Button);
    }
}
```

And you can use this `CustomComboBox` in other page like this:

```
<local:CustomComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

By default this `CustomComboBox` will show its `DropDown` list under it, unless there is no enough space under it to hold this `DropDown`, in this case, the `DropDown` will be shown above this `CustomComboBox`.

Comment: I'm kind of new to UWP and a few things I had to figure out to use this control on an xmal page. Declare your control similar to xmlns:ctrl="using:CustomComboBox" on the xmal page. To get the selected item, add this when you add the control to your page: PropertyChanged="CustomComboBox1_PropertyChanged". Then in the event, you can get the selected value like this:  var CustomCombo = (CustomComboBox)sender;  string selectedItem = CustomCombo.selectedItem;