# Change drop-down direction into upward of combobox items in uwp

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have 4 items in ComboBox When I Click combobox I need to display items only in upward directions. Please any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DropDown actually is a `Popup` control in `ComboBox`'s [Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx). We can not control it to open only in upward directions. Because the logic of where to show this popup is defined in code-behind of the default ComboBox.

I suggested that you could make a custom control and make it look like a ComboBox. You could refer to Grace Feng's solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516439/positon-of-dropdown-list-of-combobox-in-uwp) for more reference.

Comment: Thank you so much Xavier